# Get Matplotlib plots labels coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to access to all labels coordinates in a plot.

For example, I draw 2 lines and show a legend:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2],label="first_image")
plt.plot([2,1],label="second_image")
plt.legend()
plot.show()
```

I would like to get the position of all the circled labels in the following image:

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "get the position"? would you like to move the labels or simply find out where they are?

Comment: I would like to know where they are, in pixel

Comment: I think it would help to tell us about the purpose of finding those positions. Although I gave a direct answer to your question below, I fear that you currently think that those pixel positions might help you achieving something which can most probably achieved more easily using a different method.

Answer (score 3):

You can get most of the artists' positions in window coordinates by using the `get_window_extent()` method.

To be able to use this method, the artist needs to have previously been drawn to the canvas. This can be manually triggered via `plt.gcf().canvas.draw()`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2],label="first_image")
plt.plot([2,1],label="second_image")
leg = plt.legend()

plt.gcf().canvas.draw()
ticks = [t for t in plt.gca().get_xticklabels()]
for i, t in enumerate(ticks):
    print "Label {}, data: {}".format(i, t.get_text()), t.get_window_extent()
print "Legend location: ", leg.get_window_extent()
for i, l in enumerate(leg.texts):
    print "Label {}, {}".format(i, l.get_text()), l.get_window_extent()
plt.show()
```

This will print all the relevant coordinates

```
Label 0, data:  Bbox(x0=102.545454545, y0=43.0777777778, x1=102.545454545, y1=43.0777777778)
Label 1, data: 0.0 Bbox(x0=91.6079545455, y0=29.0777777778, x1=113.482954545, y1=43.0777777778)
Label 2, data: 0.2 Bbox(x0=181.789772727, y0=29.0777777778, x1=203.664772727, y1=43.0777777778)
Label 3, data: 0.4 Bbox(x0=271.971590909, y0=29.0777777778, x1=293.846590909, y1=43.0777777778)
Label 4, data: 0.6 Bbox(x0=362.090909091, y0=29.0777777778, x1=384.090909091, y1=43.0777777778)
Label 5, data: 0.8 Bbox(x0=452.272727273, y0=29.0777777778, x1=474.272727273, y1=43.0777777778)
Label 6, data: 1.0 Bbox(x0=542.454545455, y0=29.0777777778, x1=564.454545455, y1=43.0777777778)
Label 7, data:  Bbox(x0=102.545454545, y0=43.0777777778, x1=102.545454545, y1=43.0777777778)
Legend location:  Bbox(x0=419.305555556, y0=214.431597222, x1=569.055555556, y1=260.768402778)
Label 0, first_image Bbox(x0=463.75, y0=241.072222222, x1=541.375, y1=255.212847222)
Label 1, second_image Bbox(x0=463.75, y0=219.987152778, x1=563.5, y1=234.127777778)
```

Note however that it is in general not required or recommended to use those coordinates for any manipulations inside the figure, since they may change for every redraw. Depending on the usage case there might be better methods to achieve a certain goal.

Also note that those coordinates are not necessarily the pixel coordinates in the saved image. Those will depend on the `dpi` setting which may be different between on-screen and saved image. Also the backend used for saving may redraw the canvas which can possibly change the coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to reposition the legend, you can use something like this..

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

line1, = plt.plot([1,2],label="first_image", linestyle='--')
line2, = plt.plot([2,1],label="second_image", linewidth=4)

# Create a legend for the first line.
first_legend = plt.legend(handles=[line1], loc=1)

# Add the legend manually to the current Axes.
ax = plt.gca().add_artist(first_legend)

# Create another legend for the second line.
plt.legend(handles=[line2], loc=4)

plt.show()
```

Alternatively you can use `matplotlib.legend_handler` and `Axis.set_label_position`

Comment: Well, no, I just need the coordinates to manipulate the image later. Thank you anyway.