# Creating custom axes in matplotlib without affecting displayed image

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

How do I create custom axes on a matplotlib plot without affecting the displayed data?

I want to plot some data with an image (from which the data is) below the plot itself with the same axes as the data plot.

For the plotted data I've adjusted the x-axes by using `np.linespace()` but I cannot do that for an image.

Below are an exemplary picture and code example of what I was able to create myself.
What I try to do is that the x-axes of the image subplot shows the same ticks and labels as the data subplot. This should not change the appearance of the display data or image itself only the axes ticks/labels.

[image]

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#create figure
fig, axs=plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(6, 4), dpi=300)

#plot example function in subplot 0
time = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
axs[0].plot(time, np.sin(time))
axs[0].set_xlim(0-2, 10+2)

#load image
img = cv.imread(r"lena.png")
#convert BGR to RGB
RGB_img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

#show image in subplot 1
axs[1].imshow(RGB_img)
axs[1].set_xlim(0-2, img.shape[1]+2)
axs[1].get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
```

Comment: `fig, axs=plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, sharex=True)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang Then the ticks and labels are only displayed on the image subplot not on the data and it crops the image to fit the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Incorporated OP's suggestions to automate the process.

You can set arbitrary tick marks and labels with `ax.set_xticks()` and `ax.set_xticklabels()`. Combining this with `ax.get_xticks()`, it is possible to compute the image ticks from the original ticks:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

#create figure
fig, axs=plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(6, 4), dpi=300)

#plot example function in subplot 0
time = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
axs[0].plot(time, np.sin(time))
axs[0].set_xlim(0-2, 10+2)

#load image
img = mpimg.imread(r"lena.png")

#show image in subplot 1
axs[1].imshow(img)
axs[1].set_xlim(0-2, img.shape[1]+2)
axs[1].get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

# convert the ticks from the data to the pixel values
ticks_new = axs[0].get_xticks() * (img.shape[1] / 10)
axs[1].set_xticks(ticks_new)

# set labels
tick_labels = [int(round(x)) for x in axs[0].get_xticks()]
axs[1].set_xticklabels(tick_labels);
```

[image: sample plot]

Comment: Thanks this is a great help.
But lets say I know which pixel from the image corresponds to which x-value in the data plot, is there a way I can get the x ticks used in the data subplot as a list or something to automize the whole procedure to be independent of the picture used?

For context: Lets say the image in real life is 10cm wide thats why there the data goes from 0-10 and that the image is 100 pixels wide thats the step increments in  `np.linspace(0,10,100)`. Now how do I match the two scale with that knowledge?

Comment: @GittingGud, yes, there is a way. You can use `ax.get_xticks()`. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44012436/python-matplotlib-get-position-of-xtick-labels

Comment: Figured that out myself and wrote the answer just as you commented.
Do you want to adapt your answer with my additions and then I would accept your answer instead of my own?