# How to get tick labels in matplotlib prior to calling plt.show()?

Tags: matplotlib

Seems like a trivial thing, but surprisingly doesn't work. The code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.plot(np.random.rand(10))
plt.draw()
print(ax.get_xticklabels())
plt.show()
# here I close the figure manually
print(ax.get_xticklabels())
```

produces:

```
[Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, '')]
[Text(-2.0, 0, '−2'), Text(0.0, 0, '0'), Text(2.0, 0, '2'), Text(4.0, 0, '4'), Text(6.0, 0, '6'), Text(8.0, 0, '8'), Text(10.0, 0, '10')]
```

Thus you can see that the values are filled only after `show()` is called, how can I access them before that? And besides, why are they not accessible? I was thinking a call to `draw()` is sufficient. Matplotlib is 3.3.4.

Comment: what do you mean? simply ``a = ax.get_xticklabels()`` and ``print(*a)`` will already give you following output: ``Text(-2.0, 0, '−2') Text(0.0, 0, '0') Text(2.0, 0, '2') Text(4.0, 0, '4') Text(6.0, 0, '6') Text(8.0, 0, '8') Text(10.0, 0, '10')`` without even the need of actually plotting anything

Comment: @Karina This depends on the environment where you are running Python and matplotlib, and the employed backend. About the "why": the backend tries not to lose time on creating partial plots if they are not needed.  `plt.draw()` might be showing stuff in the background, so `ax.get_xticklabels()` might be called too early. `plt.pause(...)` instead of `plt.draw()` could  give the system enough time

Comment: @JohanC thank you, indeed it works with pause(), but I have no idea why. This is a bit weird, because seems like while batch plotting (and saving to file) I can't actually access these labels.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44012436/python-matplotlib-get-position-of-xtick-labels There a suggestion is to save the figure twice.

Comment: Or force a draw with fig.draw_no_output().  Or see https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/20345